# I am getting error while updateQueryData in rtk query, how do I fix this?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I am new to react query and tried many tutorials still I am not logging anything and nothing happens after the following code, cannot even log new data, It doesnt feel like there is any error. POST is working perfectly.

```
   addCategory: builder.mutation({
  query: (body) => ({
    method: "POST",
    url: apiLinks.categoryPUT,
    body: body,
  }),
  async onQueryStarted(body, { dispatch, queryFulfilled }) {
    try {
      const res = await queryFulfilled;
      const id = _.get(res, "data.data.InsertedID", Date.now());

      dispatch(
        categoryApi.util.updateQueryData(
          "getAllCategory",
          undefined,
          (data) => {
            const newBody = { id, ...body };
            console.log({ data, newBody });  //nothing shows here
            data.push(newBody);
          }
        )
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.log({ error });  // nothing logs here
    }
  },
}),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was I used this: useGetAllCategoryQuery("getAllCat"); to fetch data.

```
useGetAllCategoryQuery("getAllCat");
```

so it should be:

```
categoryApi.util.updateQueryData(
          "getAllCategory",
          "getAllCat", //change here
```

seems its a unique identifier for cache data